# Get position from Translation and Scale Matrix (Direct2D)

Tags: matrix, transformation, direct2d

I have a 2D camera defined by Direct2D 3x2 matrix like this :

```
ViewMatrix = ScaleMatrix * TranslationMatrix;
```

But when trying to do hit testing, I get at a point where I need to know my X,Y camera coordinate. I tried to keep track of hit in a vector but without success, scaling with offset center complicate a lot the work..

So I guess it should be possible to find my camera coordinate from these two matrix right ? But how ?

Thank a lot for help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to transform (X,Y) with ViewMatrix? If so it's simple (X',Y') = ViewMatrix * (X,Y). Translation components don't add extra complexity, for instance X' = X *_11 + Y*_21 + _31, similar for Y'.

Comment: My problem is that I do offseted scale. So I need to reverse this scale matrix also. But I got a workaround now. No offseted scale matrix. I translate manually. This is now manageable.